# Makefile rule that detects any changed file in a directory (and subdirs)

Tags: makefile

I want to create a `Makefile` rule that runs whenever anything is changed inside a directory (which contains multiple source files in different languages, and at different subdirectory levels).

As an example, take this `Makefile`:

```
newest: src
        touch newest
```

with a tree like:

```
src/
src/a
scr/subdir/
scr/subdir/c
```

First time I run `make`, `newest` is created all right. But if I now `touch src/subdir/b`, `make` does nothing.

Is it possible at all to create such a rule?

Comment: Use recursive makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to use something like `FILES := $(shell find src -type f)` and a rule of `newest: $(FILES)` to get the sort of behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that will do for my project.

Comment: How does this work?